# Getting 404 Error during login using oAuth and RestSharp in C# for WP

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, oauth-2.0, restsharp

I'm getting 404- Not Found error during google's authentication in windows phone 7.5 app.

```
   public void login()
    {
        var cli = new RestClient("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth");
        cli.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(user, password);

        var request = new RestRequest("token", Method.POST);

        cli.ExecuteAsync(request, response => 
        {
            MessageBox.Show(response.Content);
        });
    }
```

I given valid login credential, but its shows the response as 404-NotFound. could please help me to resolve this issue

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the URI is probably not formed correctly.

If you check [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login) you'll notice an example URI which obviously works if you click on it. That means that the service exists and everything is OK with it. You are doing something wrong with RestSharp, and for that I recommend a detailed tutorial available on CodeProject called *[Google OAuth2 on Windows Phone](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/321291/Google-OAuth2-on-Windows-Phone)*

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i gone through both the documentation. there, after the successful login they access the user profile. In my case i don't want to access the user's profile. just i need to validate the credentials, for successful credentials i'll continue with my app. otherwise i won't allow them.. this is my scenario..